# Initialising vector of vector on the heap

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function that takes in the number of rows and columns and initialises a vector of vector with default values of the object 'cell' and return the pointer to that vector.

```
//Cell class
class cell{
public:
    int cost, parent;
    cell(int cost = 0, int parent = 0) : cost(cost), parent(parent){}
}

//The initialisation function
vector<vector<cell> >*  init_table(int n_rows, int n_cols){
    //Error line
    vector<vector<cell> >* table = new vector<vector<cell>(n_cols)> (n_rows);

    //Some(very few) special cells need a different value so I do that here

    return table; //Return the pointer
}
```

It seems the compiler resolves (n_cols)> (n_rows) like a > operation and not create n_cols copies of cell objects and n_rows copies of vector objects. How can I initialise the vector without manually looping through and pushing default valued cells in the vector?

Comment: Why do you need a "heap" allocated vector in the first place? It seems like an unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++ compilers usually have [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), you can just do simply

```
vector<vector<cell> >  init_table(int n_rows, int n_cols)
{
    return vector<vector<cell> >(n_rows, vector<cell>(n_cols));
}
```

and writing

```
vector<vector<cell> > my_table = init_table(int n_rows, int n_cols);
```

will be as efficient as "new"-ing a vector, but this is safer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I now get it. I should initialise the outer vector with the inner vector  through it's constructor like

```
vector<vector<cell> >* table = new vector<vector<cell> > (n_rows, vector<cell>(n_cols));
```

and not as a template parameter. It is working now.

Comment: almost, gotta switch the second n_rows for n_cols